# Reactjs: Parent function call triggered by a child

Tags: reactjs

So I am building my first react project and stumbled upon following problem:
In my `App.js` (main application) I got a function and render my components:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.candidateCounter = 0;
    this.setCandidateVote = this.setCandidateVote.bind(this);
  }

 ...

 setCounter (name) {
    this.candidateCounter++;
    console.log(this.candidateCounter);
 }

 render() {
  ...
  <Candidates setCounter={this.setCounter} />
 }
}
```

The child component `Candidates.jsx` has another function and thus calls another component:

```
export class Candidates extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.AppProps = props;
  }

 ...

  registerVote(name) {
    ...
    this.AppProps.setCounter(name);
  }

 render() {
   ...
   <MyButton id={this.state.candidates[i].name} register={this.registerVote} />
 }
```

And the last component `MyButton.jsx` looks like this:

```
export class MyButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.ParentProps = props;
        this.state = { active: false }
    }

    buttonActiveHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
        if (this.state.active === false) {
            this.ParentProps.register(this.ParentProps.id);
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Button content='Click here' toggle active={this.state.active} onClick={this.buttonActiveHandler} />
        );
    }
}
```

I have successfully debugged that all functions calls are working except when the grandchild `MyButton` has triggered the `registerVote()` function in my `Candidates` module. Logging in this method gets printed but it cannot call `this.AppProps.setCounter()` from the parent App. I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCounter' of undefined

I hope this wasn't too complicated explained, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken it's because you didn't bind the `registerVote` in the constructor of your class `Candidates`. I would also suggest by calling the function using `this.props.setCounter(name)` instead of defining a variable in your constructor, since props can change.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that was it.. I have tried to bind the props call but of course that didn't work. Thanks mate!

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply bind the function in the constructor of the class as @qasimalbaqali stated in his comment.

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.registerVote = this.registerVote.bind(this);
 }
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct answer by clicking the check mark on the left of this post.